# Amazon Fire TV rooting

Tags: amazon-fire-tv

How to root Amazon Fire TV after the most recent update? I have tried xda-developers recommendations but I have encountered that after the most recent update, the suggested apks to root the device don't work anymore.

Comment: This is a place for programming Q&A, not how to root devices

Answer (score 1):

see http://www.aftvnews.com/how-to-root-the-amazon-fire-tv/ however it looks like with the more recent firmware updates Amazon have locked the device down so it can't be rooted, so unless you have an earlier build you're out of luck